# How to feed fastreports with objects

Tags: delphi, object

I'm using Embarcadero Delphi XE2,

I'm using fastreports filled with values from stringlist.

My question is this:
Can I skip the stringlist and somehow bind some object of my type list to data of fastreport?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TfrxUserDataSet and the related Events. With this component you can populate any kind of data to a report.